# Embed Twitter Widget in Android webview

Tags: android, twitter, webview, widget

I am trying to embed a twitter widget into a webview, but it feels like the JS code is not executing. All that is displayed is "Twitter by @xxxxxx"

```
WebView webView = new WebView(getActivity());

webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

String summary = "<a class=\"twitter-timeline\" href=\"https://twitter.com/"+getArguments().getString("handle")+"\" data-widget-id=\""+getArguments().getString("widgetId")+"\">Tweets by @"+getArguments().getString("handle")+"</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+\"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,\"script\",\"twitter-wjs\");</script>";
webView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);

return webView;
```

My application does have Intenet access permission

Comment: how are you handling the twitter actions like retweet/reply/favorite ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am created dynamic Embed Twitter webview..

Get idea from GooglesGuy... It may be helpful for anyone..

```
  private void addWebViewTwitter(Object twitterContent){
    if(twitterContent!=null && twitterContent.toString().length()>0){
        WebView webView=new WebView(this);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

        if(Utils.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
              webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://twitter.com",twitterContent.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8","");
        }

    }
}
```

**twitterContent**- your Embed twitterhtml content

Answer (score 7):

try webView.loadDataWithBaseUrl and set the base url to https://twitter.com

Comment: Thanks, I'd been banging my head over this one for a little while!